# Displaying sum of amount in US format

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to dispaly the sum of *AR Bal*, which is stored in an array in **USD format**.

```
{this.state.invoiceColumns.map((c)=>
<td 
    className="dashboard-search_table-row-cell" 
    style={{ lineHeight: '24px',fontWeight:'bold' }}>

        {c.ColumnName=='ARBal'?_.sumBy(provider.result,'ARBal'):''}

</td>)}
```

For calculating the sum I use the function

`_.sumBy(provider.result,'ARBal')`

For displaying *AR Bal* in USD format I want to use the code

```
new Intl.NumberFormat('en-USD', {currency: 'USD' ,style: 'currency'}).format(Number((provider.result)))
```

How can I use the code for USD format inside the `map()` function ?

**Line of Code I tried inside `map()`**

```
_.sumBy(provider.result,'ARBal').(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-USD', {currency: 'USD' ,style: 'currency'}).format(Number((provider.result))))
```

This shows Syntax error.

Comment: It would be `new Intl.NumberFormat('en-USD', {currency: 'USD' ,style: 'currency'}).format(Number((_.sumBy(provider.result,'ARBal'))))` The line you tried in map does have a syntax error here: `).(new ...`

Comment: @ Adriani6 `new Intl.NumberFormat('en-USD', {currency: 'USD' ,style: 'currency'}).format(Number((_.sumBy(provider.result,'ARBal'))))` worked